# OpenSSL EVP AES CTR 256 encryption performance for thousands of time at one time

Tags: performance, encryption, openssl, aes

I am using the OpenSSL EVP AES 256 to perform the encryption.
The general code flow would be shown as below:

```
Encrypt() {
 ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
 EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_ctr(), NULL, key, iv);

 EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &out_len, plaintext, plaintext_len);
 EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + out_len, &out_len)
}
```

But, you can see each time we need to create the context, init, and then perform the encryption.
In my user case, I need to encrypt thousands of strings at one time. It will take several seconds which is not acceptable.

And then I changed the code as following:
I want to init once and then call encryption thousands of times as I need.
But, for the second time Encrypt() will return the unexpected strings.

```
EncryptInit() {
 ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
 EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_ctr(), NULL, key, iv);
}

Encrypt() {
 EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &out_len, plaintext, plaintext_len);
 EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + out_len, &out_len)
}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this?
And How to improve the performance for my user case?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Update the question with the output of `openssl speed -elapsed -evp aes-256-ctr`. Perhaps your implementation doesn't have AESNI enabled.

Comment: Also note that you would *never* re-use a key/IV combo more than once. You *must* choose a new random (or predictably different) IV for each encryption operation (for a given key).

Comment: Depending on your situation, perhaps it would work to append N strings together into a single encryption, then break them back apart when need the decrypted result? If string never contains null character, then use that as separator. Otherwise, need some other convention, such as including string length at start of each, or some character combination that you've verified does not exist in any of the strings.